# Kellerman Compare .NET Objects: Comparing objects of different types with different property names

Tags: c#, compare

I'm comparing two objects of different types that have differences in the names of their properties.  So for example I have foo.Surname that I want to compare to bar.Lastname.

Is there any way to create a mapping (say in the ComparisonConfig) so that I can tell the comparer those two properties are the same thing?

I could just add the property in question to the ignore list and do a manual comparison for that property afterwards, but it seems like it would be neater to create a mapping.

Comment: I think automapper might allow this : http://automapper.org/

Comment: It was actually automapper that got me thinking about this in the first place, it has exactly the syntax I want, but as far as I know you can't use automapper to compare the contents of objects, it only allows you to copy the contents between objects (and also to check that the mappings are valid)?

Comment: Defo a job for auto mapper, create a third type map both types you have to the new type and then compare those?

Comment: That's clever @bUKaneer, I hadn't thought of that.  It's still a bit less neat than I'd ideally like, but it could well be the answer if there's no way to do it natively

Answer (score 4):

Sort of, I'm not sure if this would work for what you are asking. If your foo and bar classes both shared a key, this would work:

```
    var spec0 = new Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<string>>();
    spec0.Add(typeof(ChildType), new string[] { "ChildKeyName" });
    spec0.Add(typeof(ParentType), new string[] { "ParentKeyName"});

    List<Type> spec1 = new List<Type>();
    spec1.Add(typeof(ParentType));
    spec1.Add(typeof(ChildType));

    CompareLogic.Config.IgnoreCollectionOrder = true;

    CompareLogic.Config.ClassTypesToInclude = spec1;
    CompareLogic.Config.CollectionMatchingSpec = spec0;
    basicComparison.Config.MaxDifferences = int.MaxValue;
    ComparisonResult = basicComparison.Compare(NewObject, OldObject);
```